# Angular 6 directive is getting called later than the Regex expression validation due to which validation is getting failed

Tags: angular, angular-directive

While checking the validation for International format phone number, the validation is getting failed as"

What regex pattern is expecting:

123-456-7890

and custom directive below is helping me to add hyphens (-) in the ngmodel but till the custom directive adds the hyphens, regex pattern validation runs and it fails everytime.

```
import { Directive,ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[num-format]',
  host: {
    '(ngModelChange)': 'doSomething($event)'
  }
})

export class NumFormatDirective {

  constructor(public _el: ElementRef) {}
  doSomething(event) {
    var a;
    //a = this._el.nativeElement.value.replace(/^(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})$/)
    var cleaned = ("" + this._el.nativeElement.value).replace(/\D/g, '');
    var match = cleaned.match(/^(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})$/);
    if (match) {
      a = match[1] + "-" + match[2] + "-" + match[3];
      this._el.nativeElement.value = a;
      console.log(a);
    }
  }

}
```

And template:

```
<input 
  type="text" 
  num-format 
  name="phoneNo" 
  #PhoneNo="ngModel" 
  [(ngModel)]="user.phoneNo"  
  (ngModelChange)="user.phoneNo=$event" 
  placeholder="Phone Number" 
  pattern="phonePattern" 
  required />
<div *ngIf="PhoneNo.invalid && (PhoneNo.dirty || PhoneNo.touched)">
  <div *ngIf="PhoneNo.errors.required">
    <small class="text-danger validation-messages">
      Phone Number is required.
    </small>
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="PhoneNo.errors.pattern">
    <small class="text-danger validation-messages">
      Not a valid Phone Number.
    </small>
  </div>


  <!--phonePattern = /^\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}$/; ( in TS file)-->
```

Comment: You need to create a custom value accessor. This will give you the full control over the model event flow

Comment: ok, can you tell me how can I do that?